# POST httpRequest doesn't fetch all data

Tags: java, android, http-headers, http-post

I use the following function in java to connect to my php script in a server.
The script queries for an image (BLOB), encodes it (base64) and sends it back in JSON format.

The problem is that I can get some of the encoded data but not all of them. Should I use any headers on my httpRequest? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my java function:

```
 public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Print1: "+json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("Print2: "+jObj.toString());
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Here is my PHP code showing the JSON structure:

```
$response = array(
"success" => 0,
"message" => "",
"data" => "");


$stmt->bindColumn(1, $binary, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $professorName);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

$pic = base64_encode($binary);

$data = array(
    "photo" => $pic,
    "professorName" => $professorName
    );

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "We have results!";
$response["data"] = $data;
echo json_encode($response);
```

After testing I realized that if I use a small image (tested size < 1Kb) everything works as it should.

If I try to obtain a larger image (here 5 Kb) the data I obtain is cut in the middle.
The json structure doesn't arrive complete.

Here is an example of a successful transfer:

```
Print1: {"success":1,"message":"We have results!","data":
{"photo":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS~~~~more data~~~~N6GGYzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC","professorName":"cluvas"}}

Print2: {"data":{"kathigitisName":"cluvas","photo":"iVBORw0K~~~~more data~~~~AElFTkSuQmCC"},
"message":"We have results!","success":1}
```

Here an example of an unsucessful one

```
Print1: {"success":1,"message":"We have results!","data":
{"photo":"\/9j\/4AAQS~~~~more data~~~~6KKogkH\/  //unexpected end of data

Print2: {"data":{"professorName":"cluvas",
"photo":"\/9j\/4AAQS~~~~more data~~~~K+U\/Ce    //unexpected end of data
```

Comment: Please add your json response structure

Comment: It is unclear if you only miss some base64 encoded data from your image or from other objects. Please be more specific. Do you need the UTF-8 ?

Comment: I have updated the question. I believe that I miss data in my java. Since I use the exact same php code for a testing request through a browser. I get all data correctly no matter the size of the file.